# Send/sniff packets on Windows without winpcap/npcap using Python?

Tags: python, windows, scapy, packet-sniffers, winpcap

What I have to do is to do an automatic test in Python of the transmission of the Ethernet packets in certain system states.

Is there a solution for packet sending/sniffing (recording) in Python without winpcap/npcap.

I already tried Scapy, that can be used but only alongside with winpcap/npcap, but the problem is that it is not permitted to install the winpcap/npcap on the clients side - so my build is failing.

Answer (score 0):

There is only **one solution**, for sniffing you need *Npcap* or *WinPcap* which is based on *libpcap*, if you really don't want *Npcap* or *WinPcap* **you have to build the program using C++ or C** and use `pcap.h` as library.

Comment: OP specifically asked for answers without said packages.